# Cycle types of elements of normalizers of point stabilizers of transitive permutation groups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, permutations

Is the following true?

Suppose $G$ is a transitive subgroup of $S_n$ and $G_1$ is the point stabilizer of 1 in $G$.  Let $N$ denote the normalizer of $G_1$ in $G$.  Suppose $\sigma\in N\setminus G_1$ has order $k$.  Then $\sigma$ is a product of $n/k$ disjoint $k$ cycles; that is, the cyclic subgroup generated by $\sigma$ has $n/k$ orbits, all with $k$ elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That really seems very unlikely, and it is not difficult to find counterexamples. There is no reason why $k$ should divide $n$.

Try $S_5$ acting on the cosets of $A_4$, giving a subgroup of $S_{10}$. Then $N \cong S_4$, and elements of order $4$ have orbits of lengths $2$ and $4$.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  It has helped me refine my question, and I have posted it [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3220294/cycle-types-of-elements-of-centralizers-of-transitive-permutation-groups).